# Spring, MVC and strategy to reuse parts of the model

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm struggling to understand what would be the best strategy to reuse some code. Normally, I my have controllers in Spring as:

```
@Controller
public class PageX1{
  @Autowired
  HeaderService header;

  @Autowired
  CatalogService catalog;

  @RequestMapping("/test1")
  public String controller(Map<String, Object> model)  {             

    setHeaderObjectsIntoModel(model, "a param");
    setCatalogObjectsInyoModel(model, "another param", 1212, "more params");
  }

   private setHeaderObjectsIntoModel(Map<String, Object> model, String aParam){
     Object value = header.getObjectWithParam(aParam);
     model.put("key", value);  
   }

   ....
}
```

I may need to reuse the part related to service S1 in another controller, e.g.

```
@Controller
public class PageX2{
  @Autowired
  HeaderService s;

  @RequestMapping("/test2")
  public String controller(Map<String, Object> model)  {
    setHeaderObjectsIntoModel(model, "a new param");
  }
}
```

and the same for S2, and again and again.
I don't want to duplicate code. I had some idea in my mind, but nothing good I think (like having a class annotated with `@Component` that implements an interface aimed to handle the model, but I should make the parameters generic and I would like to have it specific to minimize mistakes).

What should be the right approach?
Any example is more than welcome

Comment: You want to share model attributes across multiple controllers?

Comment: it can happen, think about the categories over the header

Comment: I did not get you question and also, answer to my comment. Do you want to share some model parameters between different controllers?

Comment: I think you need to provide a more specific example; it's hard to tell exactly what sort of code you're trying to reuse.

Comment: Do you use the `@Autowired` service reference(s), `s1` and `s2`, anywhere else within the `@Controller` components, `C1` and `C2`, or are they only used within your `public String controller(Map<String, Object> model)` methods to perform the `setModel...` functions?

Comment: @SeanMickey They are service (e.g. accessing the DB) and can be used for something different. But there is some logic specific for all the templates that I want to recycle in all the controllers

Comment: @chrylis question updated

Comment: A header service? The question is still too vague and handwavy to address clearly. Possibly you are interested in either `@ControllerAdvice` with an `@ModelAttribute` or something like Groovy traits.

Comment: @chrylis using `@ControllerAdvice` looks like a good solution. But can I provide parametes to the method annotated with `@ModelAttribute` such that these parameters are relative to the current controller being called?

Comment: Did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options. First option you can have a base controller which provides the common functionality which will be inherited by your controllers

```
public abstract class AbstractPage{

   @Autowired
   private HeaderService s;

   protected Object retrieveObjectWithParam(String param){
      return s.getObjectWithParam(param);
   }
}

@Controller
public class PageX1 extends AbstractPage{

  @RequestMapping("/test1")
  public String controller(Map<String, Object> model)  { 
    Object headerParam = retrieveObjectWithParam("a param");
    model.put("key" , headerParam);
  }
}
```

Second option is to use @ControllerAdvice annotated class that provides common model attributes for your controllers

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class PageAdvice{

    @Autowired
    private HeaderService s;

   @ModelAttribute("headerParam")
   public Object retriveHeaderParm(){
      return s.getObjectWithParam("a param");
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, I had to finish some code at work. So, the controller advice solution is really nice. I'm wondering how to pass parameters to the method that uses the @ModelAttribute to have the value calculated based on the current controller